# If the distribution of $X$ is defined conditionally on variables $Z,W$, and we only use $W$ to estimate $X$, can $E(X)$ be defined?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo

Suppose that $X,Z,W$ are random variables and that we are interested in estimating the expectation of $X$, $E(X)$. Suppose that the distribution of $X$ is defined as:

$$
X\mid Z=z, W=w \sim \mathcal{F}_{Z,W}
$$

That is, $X$ is conditionally defined with respect to values of $Z$ and $W$. Suppose now that we would like to find $E(X)$ through a sampling procedure

$$
E(X)=E_{W}\bigg(E_{Z\mid W}\left(E\bigg(X\mid Z,W\bigg)\mid W\right)\bigg)
$$

If a sampling procedure were to be taken, it would be

1. Draw a value of $w$ from the distribution of $W$.
2. Draw a value of $z$ from the conditional distribution of $Z\mid W$.
3. Draw a value of $x$ from the conditional distribution of $X\mid Z,W$.

I would then like to know what happens if we **instead** do the following procedure:

$$
E_{W}\bigg(E\bigg(X\mid W\bigg)\bigg)
$$

That is, we

1. Draw a value of $w$ from the distribution of $W$.
2. Draw a value of $x$ from the conditional distribution of $X\mid W$.

By the iterated expectations, or the tower property, the above should be equal to $E(Y)$. However, I am unsure if such a thing can be defined, and what this sort of phenomena is normally referred to.

For example, if the issue is that $X$ needs $Z,W$ to be defined, we can rewrite as:

$$
E\bigg(X\mid W=w\bigg)= \sum_z E\bigg(X\mid W, Z=z\bigg)P\left(Z=z\mid W=w\right)
$$

Would it then be a sum of distributions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the tower property for conditional expectations, it is *always* possible to write
$$
\tag{1}
\label{1}
E[X]
= E\big[E[X \mid W]\big]
$$
for *any* random variables $X$ and $W$ (provided the expectation $E[X]$ exists).

This is easiest to see for discrete random variables: if $X$ and $W$ are discrete, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[X]
&= \sum_x x P(X = x) \\
&= \sum_x x \sum_w P(X = x, W = w) \\
&= \sum_x x \sum_w P(X = x \mid W = w) P(W = w) \\
&= \sum_w \left(\sum_x x P(X = x \mid W = w\right) P(W = w) \\
&= \sum_w E[X \mid W = w] P(W = w) \\
&= E\big[E[X \mid W]\big].
\end{aligned}
$$

In particular, \eqref{1} holds no matter what the relationship between $X$ and $W$ is; $X$ might be most easily defined in a conditional way depending on $W$, or it may be independent of $W$, or anything in between.

In your particular example, where the distribution of $X$ is most easily described by conditioning on random variables $W$ and $Z$, it is probably easiest to actually compute the expectation of $X$ as an expectation of iterated conditional expectations; e.g.,
$$
E[X]
= E\big[E\big[E[X \mid W, Z] \,\big|\, W\big]\big]
$$
or
$$
E[X]
= E\big[E\big[E[X \mid W, Z] \,\big|\, Z\big]\big].
$$
However, it is still correct to say that
$$
E[X]
= E\big[E[X \mid W]\big]
$$
or
$$
E[X]
= E\big[E[X \mid Z]\big],
$$
even if actually computing these expectations might be infeasible.

Comment: What is confusing me is that if my distributional assumption is $X\mid Z=z, W=w \sim \mathcal{F}_{Z,W}$, how will $E[X\mid W]$ make sense or be defined? Will it still be valid to have $E[X] = E\big[E[X \mid W]\big]$?

Comment: @user321627 the distributional assumption doesn't have anything to do with whether $E[X \mid W]$ is defined. Even with that distributional assumption, $X$ is still just a random variable so all the usual rules for random variables (e.g., the tower property) apply to it

Comment: I guess I am having a hard time seeing why. Do you have an example for this?

Comment: @user321627 I’m not sure what kind of example you’re looking for. There is a proof of why $E[X]=E[E[X\mid W]]$ in the answer (for the discrete case). Do you have any questions about why that proof is correct?